# HTTP Pseudostreaming using PHP w/ ffmpeg to JW Player

Tags: php, flash, video-streaming, http-streaming

We're trying to do HTTP Pseudostreaming from a PHP source that's outputting the results from ffmpeg.

Below is the code we're using to output the stream. If I access this URL directly (../stream.php) an flv file is downloaded. If I use that flv file as the source in JW Player, it works without a problem. However, when I have stream.php as the source, it doesn't work and I get the error : "Error loading player:
No playable sources found"

The code we're using in stream.php is:

```
 header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
 header("Content-type: video/flv");
 header("X-Mod-H264-Streaming: version=2.2.7");

 $cmd = 'ffmpeg -re -i source.mp4 -map_chapters -1 -vcodec:0 copy -b:v:0 885918 -bf:0 2 -threads:0 0 -s:0 720x404 -partitions:0 +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -acodec:1 copy -b:1 104684 -ac:1 2 -ar:1 44100 -f flv -';

  if ($handle = popen($cmd, 'r')) {

    sleep(3);

    echo fread($handle, 8024000);
    ob_flush();

    while (!feof($handle)){
        echo fread($handle, 8024000);
        ob_flush();
    }

    pclose($handle);

  }
```

Our JW Player code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file : "/stream.php?start=0",
        provider : 'http',
        'http.startparam' :'start',
        flashplayer : '/js/jwplayer.flash.swf',
              autostart : 'true',
              allowscriptaccess:'always',
              modes: [
            {type: 'html5'},
            {type: 'flash'},
            {type: 'download'}
        ],
        height: 270,
        width: 480
        });
</script>
```

Any ideas what could be wrong with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

jwplayer has problem with reading (urlencoding special characters like ? & ) vars in that format

best way is to do rewrite url for stream.php in htaccess :

```
RewriteRule  ^stream-video/(.*)/(.*) stream.php?token=$1&file=$2 [QSA,L]
```

This way you could pass file url with :

```
http://example.com/stream-video/token-optional/filename-or-id.mp4
```

Hope this helps..

btw did you have luck with flv streaming via php and X-Mod-H264-Streaming?